# Content issue when add an fixed header with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have developed a header with HTML. When you scroll more then 25px, the class `fixed` is added to the header with jQuery. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPXYKj

The class `fixed` has the following properties:

```
header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 1055px;
}
```

Just the basic stuff of a fixed header.
This is working, and after 25px it will scroll with you, but as you can see, the content will jump to above, because the height of the header is not anymore `relative` to the rest.

Hence my question. How to solve this problem so that the content remains in its original position, preferably without using absolute positioning.

I tried to add the class `fixed` to the body element and then call in my css the main part and add a margin-top to the main element, but then, When you scroll down and up, the main content is getting to low.

Comment: Do you know that you have given a `  margin-top: 25px;` ??? When I remove that there is no space at the top anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set a top margin for the `main` element as soon as the header is made fixed ; your content will keep its vertical offset, preventing it from "jumping". To achieve this, you may either add a class to the `main` element, or use the little known adjacency selector :

```
header.fixed + main {
  // 75px header height + 25px header top margin
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

`header.fixed + main` selects `main` elements following a `header` element with class `fixed`.

Demonstration of this pure CSS solution [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJapzK).

Comment: This is working, but if the header is inside a container div, and the main container is a sibling of the container that contains the header, how can I select it then?

Comment: Then I would advise applying the class on the container instead of the header, and style the header using `#container.fixed > header` (or give the container itself fixed position). You can then do `#container.fixed + main` for the margining part.

Answer (score 0):

```
header{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1115px;
}
header.fixed{
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `padding-top` to the content when you are making the header fixed. See this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  function fixedHeader() {
      // Global variables
      var offset = 25;

      // Scroll function
      $( window ).scroll(function () {

        // Where the magic happens
        if (window.pageYOffset > offset ) {
          $("header").addClass(' fixed');
          $(".content").addClass(' content-top');
        }

      });

    } fixedHeader();
  
  });
```

```css
header { 
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%; 
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  background: #1ed761;
}

.content-top {
    padding-top:100px;
}

section { padding-top: 30px;}
main > div {margin-bottom:30px;}

.fixed {
  position:fixed!important;
  top: 0;
  width: 1115px;
  z-index: 10;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header class="row">
    Header
  </header>
  
  <main class="content">
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x325">
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</div><!-- End .container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `else` statement in the `window.pageYOffset` condition

```
if (window.pageYOffset > offset ) {
    $("header").addClass(' fixed');
} else {
    $("header").removeClass('fixed');
}
```

which pretty much removes the `.fixed` class and brings the header element to its original state.